# How to selectively delete a function together with its matching sets of brackets?

Tags: editing

For example, suppose I want to retain only the content inside the argument of `Distribute`

```
Distribute[...Lengthly list of expressions ...] 
+ Distribute[...Lengthly list of expressions ...] + ..
(hundreds of such terms)
```

I could do a full document delete of the search item `Distribute[` but would not be able to do the same for `]` since the closing bracket may appear in other places where I want it to remain.

Comment: Quick and dirty fix:  Find and replace `Distribute` with `Identity`.  But I'm sure you're looking for something more elegant.

Comment: If your want to actually edit the code, then I don't think it's related to _Mathematica_. I'd try with Vim, emacs or perl, etc.

Comment: `ctrl+F` and [this](https://i.imgur.com/GTHglA9.png).

Comment: Ok. Identity it is...